# Using a reactive value in an IF-statement in the UI in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a conditional UI in Shiny that depends on the input of a user. I specifically want to do the if in the UI part and NOT in the server part.

Here is an example of what I aim to accomplish.

```
# app.R

library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::headerPanel(title = "Basic App"),
  shiny::sidebarPanel(
    shiny::sliderInput(inputId = "a",
                       label = "Select an input to display",
                       min = 0, max = 100, value = 50
    )
  ),
  if(output$out < 50){
    shinyjs::hide(shiny::mainPanel(h1(textOutput("text"))))
  }else{
    shiny::mainPanel(h1(textOutput("text")))
  }

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- shiny::renderText({
    print(input$a)
  })

  var <- shiny::reactive(input$a)

  output$out <- renderText({ var() })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there a way that I can use the reactive value in the UI part of the function?

Comment: why do you want to have the condition in the UI. Small hint it is not possible the way you are doing it but I need to know your motivation to make a solution that does what you want

Comment: Hi @BertilBaron. The reason I want to use it in the UI is because I have all my UI elements coded in the server and rendered and then I only call them with UI output. I want to create conditional UI`s for different inputs from radioButtons and I thought that it would be the easiest to code it in the UI side instead of the server side. Thank you for the answer below. I will try and incorporate it in my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `conditionalPanel` could be a good solution for what you want to do

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::headerPanel(title = "Basic App"),
  shiny::sidebarPanel(
    shiny::sliderInput(inputId = "a",
                       label = "Select an input to display",
                       min = 0, max = 100, value = 50
    )
  ),
  shiny::mainPanel(
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.a > 50",
      h1(textOutput("text")))
    )

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- shiny::renderText({
    print(input$a)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this helps!!